# Can I update Electron version in a project based on an Electron boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, electron

## Problem:

I've created a project based on this Electron-Vue boilerplate:

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

The problem is, it's not really being maintained, it uses an outdated version of  Electron (which also means it uses an outdated version of node.js)

## Question:

- Can I update the Electron version to the latest or it's going to break something?
- If yes, how do I do it? do I just run upgrade commands for all related to Electron dependencies?:

  `yarn upgrade electron --latest`

  `yarn upgrade electron-debug --latest`
  ... etc
  ?

Comment: yep...that should work. But there is no telling what will happen with the Electron API calls (that may be out of date).  But his has worked for me in the past. You'll have to do a little tinkering to get it working most likely.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks for the info, I'm gonna try upgrading all the electron packages and see what happens

Comment: please back up your project first!

Comment: @RandyCasburn sure thing, I've learned my lessons in the past, I always do backups now. Thanks

Comment: @RandyCasburn hey it worked!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.